# What to do about stubborn Askers?

Tags: discussion, edits, rollback-wars

By "stubborn", I mean a user that will ask a question, then edit back any improvements made to the post.

I've had this happen a few times, where I edit a post by fixing typo's, and the asker, in retaliation will re-edit, and put the typos back into the question.

I could go back and forth with editing the post again and again, but to what end?  I'd rather not spend all day arguing about an edit.

Comment: Leave them  with a close vote .... -P

Comment: If the question isn't clear without the edits and the OP is adamant on keeping it in that state, then vote to close as "unclear".

Comment: it's less of "unclear", it's just general improvements to the readability of the post that get rolled back by the user.  I generally ignore it, but i was curious if there was something I could do about this, other than leave it be ;)

Comment: @sircapsalot Basically what we're telling you is to stop wasting your time. :) There are so many questions out there that you shouldn't need to put up with uncooperative OPs.

Comment: You could wait a few days, weeks, or months (e.g., the Stack Exchange built-in bookmarks feature makes it really convenient to manage an edit queue). After they have got their answer and moved on they are far less attached to the question. Copy editing is for the long term.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If a user is vandalizing their own post flag it for moderator attention.  Mods have the appropriate tools (such as the ability to lock the post) to deal with such problematic users; you don't.

You *could* also comment first (although this step is 100% optional); for example, you may have made an error in your edit, misunderstood something in the post, or simply had a conflicting edit because you and the OP were editing the post at the same time.  As soon as you're confident the user was knowingly rolling back productive edits though, don't bother trying to resolve the problem on your own; flag and move on.  Discussing the point with the OP after that point isn't productive.

Whatever you do, don't get into an edit war.  Unless you're able to work it out in comments (i.e. you figure out it was just an edit conflict) don't edit the post any more.

Comment: sorry.. just remembered i didn't accept ;)