# An edit I made to a question's title was rolled back... Where and how can I discuss this?

Tags: discussion, edits, rollbacks

I edited (perhaps too much) a title so that it would bring clarity. I did the edit after I replied to the OP by the way...

Here is a screenshot of the [edit history for the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/35676226/revisions).

[image: Edit history]

Where can I discuss this with Eser?

Comment: Relates to http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/309509/what-to-do-when-op-rolls-back-a-clarifying-edit

Comment: You can @ ping any editor of a post in the comments of the post.  I wouldn't bother in this case, the edit doesn't seem to improve anything, the question's just off-topic.  Just move on.

Comment: It doesn't need a discussion. His rollback was clearly wrong, but it is not your job to educate him. Avoid engaging in an edit war; flag for moderator attention and explain that a user is rolling back a constructive edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can come here with such a question or ping the editor @Eser under the edited post. You can take the editor to a chat room to avoid prolonged discussion under the SO post.

When discussing a SO post, I think adding a link to the meta post under the SO post is a good idea.

I pinged the editor with a link to this meta post.

> @Eser please see this – [Ms Yvette 2016-02-28 04:15:49Z](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35676226/explain-to-me-what-would-be-insecure-about-this#comment59035541_35676226)

I rolled back the editor rollback, as your edit improved the question, it gave immediate understanding of the question from what was a vague title.

If the title is rolled back again, it may trip an [automatic moderator flag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/306821/3956566), or you [could flag a moderator for attention](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/306821/3956566).

In future if a user rolls back a valid edit like this you can roll back the change and if the editor insists on rolling back a second time, flag for a moderator.

You can also pop into the [SOCVR chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) to discuss these things.

Comment: Just trying to verify at what point a mod flag is automatically generated.